# Show text when text overflows a div

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, overflow, hidden

I am building a series of tiles on a page, where all tiles are of the same size( 370px x 370px). When the text overflows a div, the overflown part of the text is hidden and a hidden scrollbar appears. Now I would like the scrollbar to remain hidden but also have some image or text indicating that there is more text hidden on a particular tile.

The "Read more" link would appear, indicating to hover over the div and read more.

Below is sth. I was thinking of

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    if($('p').height() > ('div').height())
    {
        $(this).html('Read more');
    }
    });
```

I'm sure my code above is wrong therefore I would be grateful if someone could give me a hint.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you at least try it? Checking if the size of the overflowing element is larger than the parent seems like one way to do this?

Comment: I tried a few things man but i'm pretty hopeless with my jquery/javascript skills :(

Comment: I'd suggest starting from setting div's overflow to none and resizing the div when (for example) a click event on a button appears.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check every single div, not just a *global set*. You can use filter for that :

```
 $('div').filter(function(){
      return $(this).height() < $(this).find('p').height();
 }).append('<span>Read more...</span>)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions; didn't really work; now let's try to approach it a bit differently. If a div has a scrollbar, do sth. How would you approach it?

Comment: @Jack What happened? Any error in console? Did you check the DOM?

Comment: It doesn't give ma any error but doesn't do anything either :(

Comment: @Jack Check the DOM, the span is probably there but you can't see it since your div is `overflow : hidden`. Setting the div position to relative and the span in absolute (top 0 left 0) should show it.

Comment: i tried it but still nothing; the Read more doesn't appear anywhere

Answer (score 0):

We do this all the time and have come up with this solution (pure javascript):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.setTimeout(showScroll, 1000);
  window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    showScroll();
  });
  function showScroll(){
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("responsive-table").length==1)
    {
      var e = document.getElementsByClassName("responsive-table")[0];
      if(e.scrollHeight > e.clientHeight || e.scrollWidth > e.clientWidth){
        e.classList.add("responsive-table-scroll");
      }
      else{
        e.classList.remove("responsive-table-scroll");
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

With the CSS:

```
.responsive-table{
    overflow-x:auto;
}

.responsive-table-scroll:before{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    margin:10px;
    font-style:italic;
  content:"Scroll to see more -->";
}
```

This is applied to a table element, but you can use it with any class selector.  You can even modify it to show either horizontal or vertical overflow indicators.